# Как не выйти за пределы списка? Python

Tags: python

Мое задание:

Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы суммировать различия между последовательными парами в массиве в порядке убывания.

Пример
[2, 1, 10]  -->  9
В порядке убывания: [10, 2, 1]

Сумма: (10 - 2) + (2 - 1) = 8 + 1 = 9

Если массив пуст или массив имеет только один элемент, результатом должно быть: 0

Вот мой код:

```
    a = sorted(arr)[::-1]
    b = [a[i:i+2] for i in range(len(a)-1)]
    c = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        for j in range(len(b[i])):
            try:
                c.append(int(b[i][j]-b[i][j+1]))
            except IndexError:
                break
    return sum(c)
```

Постоянно спасаюсь try, exept чтобы не вылезать за пределы, возможны другие способы?

Comment: меня просто похоронило решение человека написавшего: return max(arr) - min(arr) if arr else 0

Comment: за пределы чего? и в чем конкретная проблема?

Comment: как например zip или что то подобное использовать не пойму, можно пример? проблема постоянно лезу за массив через вложенный цикл, может функции есть готовые?

Comment: Так вы просто напишите корректный код, чтобы не вылезать за пределы. `for j in range(len(b[i]))` — вот здесь значение `j` может принимать значения `0` и `1`. `b[i][j+1]` — вот здесь `j+1` это `1+1` = `2` — получился выход за пределы

Comment: задание я вроде написал... а вопрос мой конкретно как не уйти за пределы списка уже который раз пишу эти вложенные циклы ничего в голову другое не лезет

Comment: b[i][j+1] так и думал, но почему то компилятор не пускает меня

Comment: Задание вы написали, но я тему не понимаю. Что вы изучаете здесь?  Само задание странное.

Comment: вот мне пишет компилятор: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file0.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(sum_of_differences([1, 2, 10]))#, 9)
  File "file0.py", line 8, in sum_of_differences
    c.append(int(b[i][j]-b[i][j+1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: тема помогите с альтернативой вместо вложенного списка что можно использовать в частых случаях, так вроде, просто не знаю куда обращаться ещё)

Comment: не понимаю. Даже если не вычитать из максимума минимум, то можно внутри отсортированного списка последовательно с его элементами работать. Зачем тут `b` и `c`? Да и ваш пример явно не альтернатива практическая... Не подскажу, что можно сделать, так как пример очень странный.

Comment: Если проигнорировать самое лучшее решение из первого комментария, то, например — очень страшно, но зато спортивно в одну строчку `sum_of_differences = lambda arr: sum(a - b for a, b in zip(arr.sort(reverse=True) or arr, arr[1:]))`

Comment: @Сергей Решение из первого комментария работает при единичной длине

Comment: @MBo, да, верно, спасибо. Не учел, что 0 и результат и код здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить куда проще, и для этого не понадобится никаких `try-except` — если, конечно, они не требуются в ТЗ.

1. Сортируем исходный массив в порядке убывания (можно тот же, `arr`, можно другой, я буду использовать `arr`).
2. Создаём отдельную переменную `s` — сумматор соответствующих разностей пар.
3. Проходим одним циклом через все индексы от первого и последнего не включая, с ним берём текущий и предыдущий элементы массива и вычисляем разность. Так как массив уже отсортирован по убыванию, то модуль необязателен.
4. Все получившиеся текущие разности суммируем с `s`.
5. После цикла выводим сумму.

```py
arr = [2, 1, 10]
# сортируем в убывающем порядке: # https://pythonz.net/references/named/list.sort/
arr.sort(reverse = True)
s = 0

for i in range(1, len(arr)):
  s += arr[i - 1] - arr[i]

print(s) # 9
```

Как видите, мы обходимся всего лишь одним циклом и массивом и заметно упрощаем программу для понимания и использования :)

Comment: а зачем это вообще - что это дает-то? Я так и написал ранее: "Даже если не вычитать из максимума минимум, то можно внутри отсортированного списка последовательно с его элементами работать. " Но есть и проще - `return max(arr) - min(arr) if arr else 0`

Comment: @Сергей тот комментарий я не прочёл; вариант с разностью максимума и минимума, действительно, валиден

Comment: Ооо что то новенькое для меня arr.sort(reverse = True) :)

Comment: отмечу как ответ спасибо за уделенное время, но что то опять чувствую вернусь к этому вопросу по поводу выхода за границы списка

Comment: примерно то что искал через zip получается решение: def sum_of_differences(arr):
    arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
    return sum(a - b for a, b in zip(arr, arr[1:]))